# How does a House Elf know its name was called?

Tags: harry-potter

When a Wizard calls his House Elf's name, it appears. But how does the Elf know it was called?

Comment: Magical creatures knowing when their name is called is a very old and well accepted trope in magical / mythological / religious traditions all over the world. Find out how the rest of them do it, you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This obviously was never directly addressed in the books. But there *are* spells that can detect underage magic, or magic in front of muggles, or even a spell that tells the Ministry every time Voldemort's name is spoken, used once he took over the Ministry. So it can be assumed that the spell that enslaves House Elves has a similar detection built into it relating to their families, and extendable as necessary.

Comment: but dobby doesnt have a bond with Harry and yet can be summoned